# Webview is not rendering CSS properly in Android KitKat - Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created a working application using Ionic 4 which works fine in those mobile which contain Android Lollipop but when I run the same application in Android KitKat, the CSS is not rendering properly in webview. I have gone through every solution out there but those examples are useful if you are creating application in android native. I am new to Ionic. Need help regarding this issue.

Comment: have you tried cordova crosswalk plugin?

Comment: @Najamussaqib crosswalk only works if the device has chrome but the device which I am running does not contain chrome so it will not work and I know your second question will be to install chrome but that is not the option here.